# Efficiency of Filtering Clauses with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to write a relatively generic dynamic query generator and am curious about some techniques.  I have a list page with anywhere between 20 and 100 filters.  Each filter will be either "standard" in that the SqlGenerator class knows how to create the SQL or "custom" so that the filter provides the SqlGenerator with a strategy for what needs to be INCLUDEd and a WHERE clause.

1.) What is the best way to do the filtering clauses?

a) Very straightforward as far as keeping each filter separate and contained:

```
and exists (select 'x' from [company] c
            where c.CompanyId = p.CompayId
            and c.Rating >= 4)
and exists (select 'x' from [company] c
            where c.CompanyId = p.CompayId
           and c.CityId = 5)
```

b) Consolidated to a single exists but removes the need to build/manage INCLUDEs.

```
and exists (
    select 'x'
    from [company] c
    where c.CompanyId = p.CompayId
    and c.Rating >= 4 and c.CityId = 5)
```

c) Difficult to build dynamically but reads the cleanest to me and seems like it would execute most efficiently.

```
select x, y, z
from product p
join company c on p.CompanyId = p.ProductId
where c.Rating >= 4 and c.CityId = 5
```

d) I've also seen, on occasion, that putting certain pieces of the where clause in the join make queries more efficient.  Does it make sense to do this:

```
select x, y, z
from product p
join company c on p.CompanyId = p.ProductId and c.Rating >= 4 and c.CityId = 5
```

2.) Since this is dynamic, I'm afraid I'm losing all benefit of query cache plans and indexes.  Does it make sense to always include certain joins and clauses in hopes they get optimized away in order to use the same plan/indexes?

```
select x, y, z
from product p
join company c on p.CompanyId = p.ProductId
where c.Rating >= ISNULL(@Rating, c.Rating)
and c.CityId = ISNULL(@CityId, c.CityId)
```

3.) Lastly, does the order of clauses and joins affect query plan caching?  That is, if I switch the order of the AND statements, are those 2 different plans?

Comment: Note: 1c and 1d are equivalent, but 1a and 1b are both different from each other and different from 1c/1d.

Answer (score 2):

Your queries do different things.  You should choose the version that does what you want semantically.

(1a) and (1b), do different things.  Under some circumstances, they do the same thing -- notably if `companyid` is unique in the table.  I don't know whether or not that is true for this table or for other tables.

(1a)/(1b) and (1c) do different things, especially if `companyId` can be duplicated.

(1c)/(1d) -- I have never seen a difference in moving a condition from the `where` to an `on` clause for an inner join.  Of course, this can make a difference for an outer join.

(2) I would be much more concerned about using indexes rather than query caches.  Reading just a few extra data pages pretty is going to take longer than recompiling in most cases.

(3) For a long complex query, the ordering of conditions and tables can matter, but this is not generally a major concern.

Comment: Thanks, company will unique on company id.  You're right the indexes should be the bigger concern, I had thought about that but it slipped my mind when writing the question and have updated accordingly, good point.